# Simulating frequency response of switched capacitor circuit

Tags: simulation, frequency-response, switched-capacitor

A web search of "simulate switched capacitor circuit" gives several results which suggest the use of *periodic AC analysis* to find the frequency response of a switched capacitor circuit.

https://designers-guide.org/analysis/sc-filters.pdf

[https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~moon/research/files/David_Stoops_2.pdf](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/%7Emoon/research/files/David_Stoops_2.pdf)

The obvious approach to me is to apply an impulse at the input and do a DFT of the output.

Since the circuit is discrete time, the impulse would be a pulse of 1 V that would last 1 clock period, and the output should consist of values sampled at the end of every clock period.

Does this approach work, or am I missing something? I don't have access to SpectreRF to compare the two approaches.

Comment: The fastest way is to use a piece-wise linear (PWM) simulator like SIMPLIS or PSIM which can extract the ac small-signal response from a *switching* circuit. Unless you define an *average* model, you won't be able to use SPICE for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

z transform is used in such modeling if you want to do it pencil-and-paper way. From that you can get a continuous-time analog and model that in conventional way.

Otherwise, the frequency response can be obtained from frequency-stepped transient analysis. Periodic AC analysis requires much less computation, so is preferable if the SPICE program you use supports it. MicroCap 12 is free and implements it, perhaps NGSpice too? Anyway, this is only a concern with big circuits. A couple switched capacitors should be plenty fast to simulate with a stepped transient analysis.

Comment: Is stepped transient the same as simulating the impulse response? Also, are you saying the results are the same, but periodic AC is just faster?